# Bash: interpolate variables when using -v

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a bash script named `test.sh` with the following contents:

```
echo Dir: $PWD
```

When I invoke this script with the `-v` switch, I can see the commands being executed:

```
$ bash -v test.sh
echo Dir: $PWD
Dir: /Users/matt
```

Is there any way to get it to interpolate the variables of the command before executing them? I'm looking for output to be more like:

```
echo Dir: /Users/matt
Dir: /Users/matt
```

Comment: Did you try: `bash -ex ./test.sh`

Comment: First I've seen of that. Please post as an answer and I'll be glad to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could hard code it into a script. Perturb the code slightly at the begining:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -ex
   echo Dir: $PWD
   ```

   Then execute it like `./script.sh`or as and the output will be:

   ```
   + echo Dir: /Users/matt
   Dir: /Users/matt
   ```
2. You can set an option manually if you would like to use -v

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   if [ $1 = -v ] ; then
       set -ex
   fi

   echo Dir: $PWD
   ```

   Then execute it like `./script.sh`and the output will be:

   ```
   + echo Dir: /Users/matt
   Dir: /Users/matt
   ```
3. you can flag your script like `bash -ex ./test.sh` as suggested by anubhava.

note: you can execute your commands with your style of `bash` in front, above is my preference.

---

References:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `bash -x`.

```
bash -x test.sh
+ echo Dir: /Users/matt
Dir: /Users/matt
```

`-x` will run the entire script in debug mode. **Traces of each command plus its arguments are printed to standard output after the commands have been expanded but before they are executed.**